# How can I run a a method prior and after all tests are run in XUNIT, while Keeping a fixed Fixture?

Tags: c#, automation, xunit

I am trying to implement a [BeforeAfterMethodRun](https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/08/30/xunit-beforeaftertestattribute-how-to-run-code-before-and-after-test/) Though I have already a Fixture that was not written by me and is being used in other projects. Is there a way how I could add this while having another base class in my class? I get the following error:

[image]

My goal is to Execute the command prior to any of the methods in the class is called once, which can be as well called on every method call. Though these methods would not be the same and would change from class to class.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I did not understand the Attribute decoration very well. I could achieve this by  creating a new class as:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Linedata.Amp.Qa.Foundation.Logger;
using Xunit.Sdk;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
class ReportBeforeAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        Trace.Log("Starting Method");
    }

    public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        Trace.Log("MethodFinished ");
    }
}
```

And then Decorating the needed class as `[ReportBefore]`